# Configure gnome-screenshot to run a script

Tags: bash

Whenever I take a screenshot, I pretty much always want to open that screenshot and look at it. To that end, I wrote a quick script to open the most recent screenshot:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
LATEST=~/Screenshots/$(ls ~/Screenshots -rt | tail -n 1)
set -f
echo "$LATEST"
xdg-open "$LATEST"
```

Is there a way to configure gnome-screenshot to run this script each time?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply override the standard `gnome-screenshot` with your own script that calls the original binary and then performs your own commands after it finished.

To do that, just paste the script below as `/usr/local/bin/gnome-screenshot` (open your editor with root privileges or you won't be able to save it):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Call the original 'gnome-screenshot' and pass it all command-line arguments:
/usr/bin/gnome-screenshot "$@"

# Insert your own script here:
LATEST=~/Screenshots/$(ls ~/Screenshots -rt | tail -n 1)
set -f
echo "$LATEST"
xdg-open "$LATEST"
```

Don't forget to make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gnome-screenshot
```

After that, your script will be launched whenever someone runs `gnome-screenshot` (without absolute path) instead of the original executable, because the `/usr/local/bin` location has a higher priority in `PATH` than `/usr/bin`.

The keyboard shortcuts should also use the new script now by default.

Comment: Cool, but I don't run gnome-screenshot by running "gnome-screenshot" in Bash; I use the Screenshot application. Am I out of luck?

Comment: Hmm... The .desktop file responsible for the Screenshot Launcher is `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop`, but it does not specify any absolute paths. I actually don't understand why it isn't working. You could try and edit it to change all `Exec=gnome-screenshot ...` lines to `Exec=/usr/local/bin/gnome-screenshot ...` for now, but note that it won't work any more if you later remove the custom script we made and you would have to undo the changes again (so maybe make a backup copy).

Comment: Might you have generated a custom .desktop file for gnome-screenshot? Also check whether one is in `~/.local/share/applications`.